# Multithreaded filestream

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, std

I'm creating a client application that connects to a server and, besides other features, logs server chat into a file, so that rule violations may be punished later.
Unfortunatelly, it became necessary to have (at least) two threads in the application: receiver loop and sender loop - timing precesion is required by the server. This means, I need thread safe solution for logging data to a file.
This is what may happen, if threads send log information at the (as much as possible) same time:

```
logfile.txt:
chat: Hello my name is Duke
chat: Hell[WARNING]: Hacker detectedo my name is John
```

You can see one sentence injected into another. I don't want this to ever happen. Same happens to my `std::cout` output, but that is not so critical.

Questions:

1. How do I make `std::ofstream` to only log one data at a time? (remembering other and inserting it AFTER, not in the middle)
2. How do I check if the file was closed by other thread. (or an error)

Bonus question:
Could you solve same problem for `std::cout`?

Comment: You'll want to lock a mutex before writing to the file (or `std::cout`)

Comment: Just that I don't want to BLOCK the other input, but make `std` to make its own order in writing. First take one input, then another.

Comment: You can avoid blocking with dauphic's last paragraph.

Comment: There is some very interesting material about non-blocking active object-like wrappers in [this talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism). It isn't too hard to put together a working implementation (if you have C++11).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard streams have no thread safety guarantees. The only way to safely accomplish what you're trying to do is to serialize access to the stream.

The easiest solution is to wrap any statement involving the stream in a mutex.

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locked(gCoutMutex);
    std::cout << "This is a message" << std::endl;
}
```

A more correct approach, especially for a logger, is to have a logging thread with a message queue. When another thread wants to log, it just posts a message to the queue, and the logging thread will go through the queue and write everything to disk.

Comment: I have a similar thread with queue for chat messages sent to server - but the `std::vector` is unsafe too, so sometimes the application crashes.

Comment: +1 ... and, of course, a mutex will still be needed in your *more correct* approach when accessing the queue.

Comment: The standard library has nothing to help you here. You'll either need to write your own thread-safe queue or use one from another library. For example, a `boost::asio::io_service` or one of the containers in Boost.LockFree. My preferred approach is the `io_service`.

Comment: Could you please explain, what happens, when the stream is locked and another thread tries to write? Will it fail? And where does the variable in brackets come from: `locked(gCoutMutex);`? Thank you very much.

Comment: @TomášZato: If the stream is locked and another thread comes in, it will wait until the stream is unlocked. This wait can be avoided with the logging thread approach. The variable in brackets is a global `std::mutex` object; you would have to create your own.

Comment: Can the `std::mutex` be a class property? I suppose so, but I'll ask to avoid some nasty suprises later.

Comment: It will block until the lock has been released.

Comment: One more question if I may: Can the `std::mutex` be used on `std::vector`?

Comment: A mutex is a synchronization primitive; it has absolutely nothing to do with streams or containers. You should read up on threading principles before doing anything else.